# Pass ListView value to EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `listView` in Activity A as shown below.

[image]

When the first list is clicked, it should display `3` on `editText`. But it displays `5` which was actually getting from the last list.

[image]

**Activity A**

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
  ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
  int mClickedPosition;
  adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String (getActivity(),R.layout.claims,R.id.textView1,m_listItems);
 listV = (ListView) claims.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            listV.setOnItemClickListener(new 
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // when list is pressed, intent to B
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
                            mClickedPosition = position;
                            if (name.equals("Project")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Claims1.this.getActivity(), B.class);
                                intent.putExtra("bitmap", true);
                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                intent.putExtra("result", result);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                            }


            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                switch (requestCode) { // receive from B
                    case 0:
                        result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                        name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                        description = data.getStringExtra("c");
                        as = Long.parseLong(result);
                        Log.d("FIRST", "result:" + result);
                        Text = "  " + name + "                                  " + "RM" + result + "";
                        // m_listItems.clear();
                        if (mClickedPosition == -1) {
                            m_listItems.add(Text);

                        } else {
                            m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition, Text);

                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listV.setAdapter(adapter);
                        break;
                        }
```

**Activity B**

```
   if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) { //if  has value pass from A
            final String Amount = getIntent().getExtras().getString("result");
            final String description1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");
            txt1.setText(description1);
            txt.setText(Amount);
        }

                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // return to A
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                        a = "Project";
                        text = txt.getText().toString(); // amount
                        returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("a", a);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("c", c); // receive from Activity C
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                       finish();
                    }
                });
                       viewImage.setImageBitmap(Global.img); // receive from C
                  }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95347/discussion-on-question-by-tony-pass-listview-value-to-edittext).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use you `ArrayList` to extract String at position of `ListView` like..

```
listV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
           mClickedPosition = position;
           String result = m_listItems.get(position);        //add this
           result = result.substring(2);
           if (name.equals("Project")) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Claims1.this.getActivity(), B.class);
               intent.putExtra("result", result);     // your intent stuff
           }
         }
});
```

Comment: dude.. the result string is a simply containing `name + "           " + result` it'll need to parse first.. and don't forget he needs to show `3` in the `editText` not `Project        RM5`

Comment: @Mohit, the value displayed already correct. If can remove the 'name', it would be perfect :)

Comment: @Tony `String result = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).split("\s\s+")[1].replace("RM","");` you can do it this way.. but its very dirty.. your implementation is bad to start with.. don't rely on bad implementations they haunt you in the future.. :/

Comment: when you get specific string to other activity.. you can easily manipulate `String` with `.split`,`.replace` etc method...

Comment: So what should I write :?

Comment: @Tony try this forgot to escape characters`String result = ((String)listView.getAdapter().getItem(position)).split("\\s\\s+")[1].replace("RM","");`

Comment: `split` cannot be resolved as A is extends to fragment

Comment: @Tony I strongly recommend you to rethink, redesign and refactor your code and application

Comment: @Minato `Error:(73, 115) error: illegal character: '\u200c'`, `Error:(73, 117) error: ';' expected`, `Error:(73, 118) error: not a statement`

Comment: @Tony `String result = m_listItems.get(position).split("\\s\\s+")[1].replace("RM"‌​,"");` I don't know Why its giving you the `error` I've extended Mohit's answer;

Comment: If your **RM** string is constant, then you can use `result = result.substring(2);` to value integer value of your string...

Comment: @Mohit where did you change

Comment: just added `result = result.substring(2);` under your result definition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95308/discussion-between-tony-and-mohit).

Comment: @Mohit I use your code and still get `name + " " + result`

Comment: I want value display on editText only. The **RM** only display `in listView`